# How to invoke getSupportFragmentManager() or getFragmentManager() in Activity?

Tags: android

I have some questions about `DialogFragment` in Android.

I made `CustomDialogFragment` that extends `DialogFragment` and implemented `onCreateDialog()` function in it.

Now I want to show the Dialog in my `Activity`.

```
CustomDialogFragment cdf = new CustomDialogFragment();
cdf.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "myCustomDialog");
```

However I can't invoke `getSupportFragmentManager()` in my `Activity`.

so my questions are:

1. Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?
2. Do I have to use `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`?
3. What's the differences between `FragmentActivity` and `Activity`?

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager()` used in Activity while `getFragmentManager()` used in fragment

Comment: I tried to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in my Activity but the Activity could not resolve the method. I think `getSupportFragmentManager()` can be used in `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: for using `getSupportFragmentManager()` your activity should extents `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager()` is used along with the support library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity` to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in Your Activity

and use `getFragmentManager()` or `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` in `fragment`